# Odd symbol in Béla Bartók's Mikrokosmos Book 1

Tags: piano, notation, lilypond, bartok, mikrokosmos

Today I came across an odd symbol in Béla Bartók's Microkosmos.

The symbol occurs in Book 1, Score 21, Measure 8, at the end of a phrasing slur.
It looks like a vertical bar that crosses only the first 2 topmost lines of the staff and it's unmetered.

My wild guess is that is a kind of very brief, unmetered rest similar to the breath mark in vocal music ...

What it is and how can I write it in Lilypond ?

Many thanks.

[image: Strange music symbol]

PS: Yes caesura is also what I was thinking of but AFAIK is more of undetermined length rather than brief. And my guess (again :) is that the intent was for a brief separation between the expressions. Thanks for the replies :)

Comment: Maybe look at http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/typesetting-gregorian-chant#divisiones

Comment: Just in case, this is not your work, you may want to know that someone has set this in lilypond. https://bitbucket.org/benluo/mikrokosmos/src/6da850b000b38240696ef8bd043d324cebae8fc8/021-Four%20Unison%20Melodies-A4.ly?at=default But I can't see your symbol here. Maybe I took the wrong score.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe the command `\divisioMinima` shown for [Gregorian chant notation](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/typesetting-gregorian-chant#divisiones) would be a hack for you.

[image]

I have not checked, if it can be followed by a bar.

Same thing but other notation would be `f1 \bar "'" g1` which yields:

[image]

However, this both are bar lines which could confuse your lilypond interpreter. If you are not checking the bar length, it should not be a problem.

A last very hackish idea would be, to set a high note, lets say `b''4` and to hide its head. This will result in just a line. The command is `\hide NoteHead` and you can get [more inspiration here](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/expressive-marks-as-lines).

For the meaning of this sign: I don't have any reference and I don't play piano but on vibes or marimba I would have interpreted this as:

Make a break by taking your fingers away from the keys, or by releasing the pedal. Don't get slower but give it a breath. (Just my personal guess)

Answer (score 8):

The book [*Bartók's Mikrokosmos: Genesis, Pedagogy, and Style*](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=aFiPFWVDMYEC), says the following about it:

Ch 6, Nos 18-21:

> The separating sign | indicates the interruption of legato between phrases.

Ch 4, Bartók's definitions about musicianship:

> *Phrasing*. Curved (slur marks) are used to indicate legato, and they also mark the phrasing. Legato phrases are not to be separated where
>   the curved lines meet, unless they are marked with separating signs.
>   Legato phrases can be emphasized, however, by beginning them with a
>   slight dynamic shading. When two slurs meet at one note, the phrasing
>   begins and ends at that note.
>
> The separating sign | (a superscript vertical line) indicates the
>   interruption of legato between phrases. The last note of the phrase
>   preceding the sign should be played staccato or otherwise shortened.
>   The separating sing ’ (a superscript comma) also indicates the
>   interruption of legato. In this case it means a slight almost
>   unnoticeable pause in which the time of separation is taken equally
>   from the notes preceding and following the comma.

Answer (score 7):

I was also thinking of some variation of a breath mark.

http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/expressive-marks-as-curves#breath-marks

---

### Using standard breath mark:**

[image: Breath mark]

`c2. \breathe d4`

---

### Using a tick as the breath mark symbol:

[image: Using a tick as the breath mark symbol]

`\relative c'' {
  c2
  \override BreathingSign.text =
      \markup { \musicglyph #"scripts.rvarcomma" }
  \breathe
  d2
}`

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that this is a caesura, which is usually notated in the following way:

[image: caesura]

A caesura is a brief, unmeasured pause in the flow of the music. Although I am not certain, the fact that it appears in both staves and that it occurs right after a very long phrase and at the end of the measure, makes it seem likely to be a caesura.

The caesura is probably located in a breath or articulation menu in Sibelius 7.

edit: The caesura is located under symbols > common > caesura. A thick caesura is also available.

Answer (score 4):

*The meaning of this (phrase separation) symbol is explained by xvan's answer.*

---

To get this symbol in LilyPond, make a modified breath mark macro:

```
%% Phrase Separation
phraseSeparation = {
    \once\override BreathingSign.Y-offset = #0.7
    \once\override BreathingSign.font-size = #3
    \once\override BreathingSign.text = "|"
        \breathe 
}
```

and use it like this:

```
a'2-> c''4 |
b'2.\) \phraseSeparation |
e''4\( d'' e''\) |
```

output will look like this:
[image: excerpt with phrase separation mark]